# If-statement wont cout and there are no errors, (according to Xcode

Tags: c++, if-statement

Once the program gets to the if statement it just ignores it and stops. Xcode says that there are no errors so i have no clue what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string team;
    std::cout << "Welcome to The Baseball game!\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "choose a team.\n";
    std::cin >> team;

    if (team == "Arizona Diamondbacks") //this is were it stops working
    {
        std::cout << "You chose the Arizona Diamondbacks, here is your lineup:" << std::endl << "1. RF Gerrardo Parra" << std::endl << "2. 2B Willie Bloomquist" << std::endl << "3. 1B Paul Goldschmidt" << std::endl << "4. C Miguel Montero" << std::endl << "5. LF Jason Kubel" << std::endl << "6. CF A.J. Pollock" << std::endl << "7. SS Didi Gregorius" << std::endl << "8. 3B Cliff Pennington" << std::endl << "9. SP Patrick Corbin" << std::endl << "your starting pitcher will be Patrick Corbin.\n";
    }
    if (team == "Atlanta Braves")
    {
        std::cout << "you chose the Atlanta Braves";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it stops working?  What "stops"?  Looks to me like it would just return normally.

Comment: `cout` is not a verb.

Comment: @femtoRgon No, this is different. `team` is a `std::string`.

Comment: Did you make any effort to solve this yourself? Did you "std::cout << team << std::endl;" or run it through a debugger and check the value of team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its problem with your `cin >> team;` that you are using to get string input. Try using **getline**

**cin** stops input when space character appears.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> std::cin >> team;
> ```

This reads one word. If you enter "Arizona Diamondbacks", `team` gets set to `"Arizona"`. You can use `getline` instead to read a whole line of input:

```
std::getline(std::cin, team);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ifstream` extraction operator `>>` for a `std::string` extracts whitespace-delimited strings. So your `cin >> team` is stopping at the first space/tab in the users input. You'll need to use a function that reads the entire line instead.